# Using getLine1Number to get device identifiers is not recommended

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm trying to get phone number but Android Studio displays this warning.

> Using getLine1Number to get device identifiers is not recommended

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
}
```

Also `getLine1Number()` throws an `SecurityException` in same devices

Why it is not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I had been worndering the same thing and found that it's all explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids